# How to add time element to open date and close date when adding a quiz

Tags: 7, datetime, quiz

I am using the following modules.

1. [Quiz, Version 7.x-4.0-rc2](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz)
2. [Date, Version 7.x-2.9](https://www.drupal.org/project/Date)

When adding a quiz, in the availability options tab, I want to be able to set the time as well.

In the open date and close date, there should be an hour and minute option as well.

I did the following things.
1. In the `hook_form_alter()`, added the below code

```
if($form_id == 'quiz_node_form'){
  $form['quiz_availability']['quiz_open']['#type'] = 'date_select';
}
```

This gave a warning on the `node/add/quiz`page.

> Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   date_default_date()

2.So added a patch in `date_api_elements.inc`
https://www.drupal.org/files/date-element-default-value-2038057-1.patch
This removed the warning but upon adding the date and time in the availability options and saving the form, it throws the huge error below.

> Please supply a valid date. PDOException: SQLSTATE[01000]:
>
> Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'quiz_open' at row 1: INSERT INTO {quiz_node_properties} (vid, nid, aid, number_of_random_questions,
>    max_score_for_random, randomization, backwards_navigation,
>   repeat_until_correct, quiz_open, quiz_close, takes,
>   show_attempt_stats, keep_results, time_limit, pass_rate, summary_pass,
>    summary_pass_format, summary_default, summary_default_format,
>    quiz_always, feedback_time, display_feedback, tid, has_userpoints,
>   userpoints_tid, allow_skipping, allow_resume, allow_jumping,
>    show_passed, mark_doubtful, max_score) VALUES ....

3.In the `hook_node_presave`, printed the *$node*.

It stores the date as below.

```
  [quiz_open] => 2016-05-12 21:17
```

but it expects the date to be stored like this.

```
 [quiz_close] => Array(
      [month] => 6
      [day] => 11
      [year] => 2016
    )
```

How to store the date as an array or is there an alternative solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to an array using the php function [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
// lets assume $date = Array ('quiz_open' => '2016-05-12 21:17');

$year = substr($date['quiz_open'], 0, 4); // grabs 2016
$month = substr($date['quiz_open'], 5, 2); // grabs 05
$day = substr($date['quiz_open'], 8, 2); // grabs 12

$date = array ('quiz_close' => array (
                                'day' => $day,
                                'month' => $month,
                                'year' => $year,
                                     )
              );
```